# Laravel Public URL İn Jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel, owl-carousel

How can i use laravel public url in jquery code?

```html
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.categories .owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        navText: [
            '{{ URL::asset("/assets/images/next_icon.webp") }}',
            '{{ URL::asset("/assets/images/next_icon.webp") }}'
        ],
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You directly can not use the LARAVEL/PHP values in JS.
You will need a intermediate medium i.e HTML.
Create a input/any element assign the LARAVEL value to that HTML element,
Then fetch the value from the ELEMENT.
Example:-

```
<body>
    <input type="hidden" id="next_icon" value="{{ URL::asset("/assets/images/next_icon.webp") }}"></input>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var next_icon = $('#next_icon').val();
            $('.categories .owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
                navText: [
                    next_icon,
                    next_icon
                ],
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```